# Loading bot framework template in Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, azure, templates, botframework

newbie here :)

I am trying to load a template from a book I am following. The link provided on the book does not work, since the file downloaded is not a .zip. There are files in Github (https://github.com/Apress/developing-bots-w-msft-bots-framework) but in the case specifically of bot framework SDK, I don't know what are the files (since there are many in each folder) do I need to group in a .zip file to load the bot.

Could someone give me the example how can I load this EchoBot template, inside code_chapter2 folder of the github above?
Thank you very much!

Comment: you can download the source from this as a zip though..

Comment: When I download the source as a zip and put the zip in the user template folder of Visual Studio, it does not show anything to load when I browse to this path from VS bot framework...

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that somehow, their github repo download link appears to be broken. While you can appear to download, once you attempt to extract, it gives you a broken dll file error.

[image: Download link]

But good news! Given the age of the book, they're probably using V3 of the bot framework SDK, and there are alternatives to getting your hands on the code for a v3 EchoBot. Once such location is the [offical Botbuilder-v3 SDK Repo](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-V3).

Tucked inside the CSharp folder is a folder called 'Samples'. Inside THAT folder is a Echobot folder. Once you've downloaded and extracted the repo, you can use Visual Studios to open the file:

[image: EchoBotCSPROJfile]

Just double click the csproj file and if you have visual studio installed, it should open automatically. Hopefully that Echobot is close enough to the Echobot from the book that you can still follow along. If not, feel free to return to StackOverflow with any of your Bot Framework questions!

Comment: Than you JJ! I re-installed my bot builder V4 again. Have in my template file both the V3 master folder unzipped and zipped and now I do have the V3 template available. Thanks a lot! Now I can start.